# List all concrete or abstract classes of object

Tags: c#, reflection, superclass

Is it possible in C#, via reflection or some other method, to return a list all superclasses (concrete and abstract, mostly interested in concrete classes) of an object. For example passing in a "Tiger" class would return:

1. Tiger
2. Cat
3. Animal
4. Object

Comment: Reflector includes a convenient "Base Types" node that you can use to drill down into a type's interfaces and base classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
static void VisitTypeHierarchy(Type type, Action<Type> action) {
    if (type == null) return;
    action(type);
    VisitTypeHierarchy(type.BaseType, action);
}
```

Example:

```
VisitTypeHierarchy(typeof(MyType), t => Console.WriteLine(t.Name));
```

You can easily deal with abstract classes by using the `Type.IsAbstract` property.

Comment: What a surprisingly simple answer but just what I looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use the "GetType()" method to get the type of the provided object.  Each Type instance has a "[BaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx)" property which provides the directly inherited type.  You can just recursively follow the types until you find a Type with a null BaseType (ie Object)